# Replacing data entries based on ID and date from data set

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm a teacher who manages a caseload of students who have yearly meetings. Each year their services, hours, supports, etc. change. We complete a survey on each student to record all this data on a single spreadsheet. I want to pull data from those submissions to replace the students' information with the most recently dated information in our caseload master report (Tab one). If no data is entered yet I want it to remain the same.

The first tab is what we use for reporting to our team and the IEP completion tab is where the survey data is imported. I tried some solutions such as VLOOKUP with some IF statements but I don't think that is the correct route to go.

I scrubbed the [linked Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ej6US9gIyxXpCcIQ2k_8F1bbg8n6tooPvLGOcVYY49Y/edit?usp=sharing) for confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Student ID#/ID Number` is a reliable unique index in a *third* sheet create a VLOOKUP of the ID Number's associated fields from Tab1. Fields not found will error, so wrap your VLOOKUP with IFERROR and an INDEX/MATCH (because the ID there is not in ColumnA) of the fields in Tab2.